# Counting first occurrences of a disease in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to count the first occurrence of a disease (say  myocardial infarction (MI) "heart attack") but I am having a hard time implementing this in R (base or tidyverse). Any help is appreciated.

Thank you all. This works great. I realize I wasn't clear in my example.
These methods work great in general but I wanted a way to get
the incidence and prevalence by time period. 
The incidence is the proportion of new cases that occur at a particular time divided by the number of people who did not get the disease

```
n_id <- 5 # five individuals
n_time <- 4 # four time pints
id <- rep(1:n_id, each = n_time)
time <- rep(1:n_time,times = n_id)
MI <- c(0,0,1,1,
        0,1,1,1,
        0,0,0,1,
        0,0,0,0,
        0,0,0,0)
dsn <- data.frame(id, time, MI)
MI2 <- c(0,0,1,NA,
         0,1,NA,NA,
         0,0,0,1,
         0,0,0,0,
         0,0,0,0)
dsn2 <- data.frame(id, time, MI, MI2)
library(dplyr)
arrange(dsn2, time)
dsn2

#>    id time MI MI2
#> 1   1    1  0   0
#> 2   2    1  0   0
#> 3   3    1  0   0
#> 4   4    1  0   0
#> 5   5    1  0   0
#> 6   1    2  0   0
#> 7   2    2  1   1
#> 8   3    2  0   0
#> 9   4    2  0   0
#> 10  5    2  0   0
#> 11  1    3  1   1
#> 12  2    3  1  NA
#> 13  3    3  0   0
#> 14  4    3  0   0
#> 15  5    3  0   0
#> 16  1    4  1  NA
#> 17  2    4  1  NA
#> 18  3    4  1   1
#> 19  4    4  0   0
#> 20  5    4  0   0

#in the example above, it can be calculated as below
#For the incidence at each time point (proportion of new cases that occur at a particular time divided by the number of people who did not get the disease)
#time 1 = 0/5 =0
#time 2 = 1/5 =0.2
#time 3 = 1/4 =0.25
#time 4 = 1/3 =0.33

##For the prevalence at each time point (the proportion of new and old cases divided by total population)
#time 1 = 0/5 =0
#time 2 = 1/5 =0.2
#time 3 = 2/5 =0.4
#time 4 = 3/5 =0.6

time <- 1:4
incidence <- c(0/5, 1/5, 1/4, 1/3)
prevalence <- c(0/5, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5)

results <- cbind(time, incidence, prevalence)
results
#>      time incidence prevalence
#> [1,]    1 0.0000000        0.0
#> [2,]    2 0.2000000        0.2
#> [3,]    3 0.2500000        0.4
#> [4,]    4 0.3333333        0.6
```

I'd like to be able to do this for each time point and accounting for what happen at the previous time point. Would a for loop be the way to go?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

In response to your edit, here is a solution for calculating the incidence.  It also returns the correct result if the disease occurs at time 1.

```
library(dplyr) 

dsn %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(neg = MI == 1 & !duplicated(MI)) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise(d = sum(MI != 1),
            prevalence = mean(MI),
            n = sum(neg)) %>%
  transmute(time, 
            incidence = n / lag(d, default = n_distinct(dsn$id)),
            prevalence)

   time incidence prevalence
  <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1     0            0  
2     2     0.2          0.2
3     3     0.25         0.4
4     4     0.333        0.6
```

Comment: Thank you @H1. I edit the example for clarity. Any suggestions on how to go about for each time point?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter for the last row for each `id` and then calculate the proportion.

```
library(dplyr)

dsn2 <- dsn %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(n())

sum(dsn2$MI)/nrow(dsn2)
# [1] 0.6
```

Comment: Thank you @www. I edited/clarified the example for clarity (see above). Any suggestions on how to go about it for each time point?

Answer (score 0):

The edited question is more trickier to resolve than the previous one. However, here is a solution using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dsn2 %>%
  #Group by time
  group_by(time) %>%
  #Get the sum of positives and negatives, as well as total ID number
  summarize(pos = sum(MI ==1),
            neg = sum(MI ==0),
            totalID = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  #add lagged entry of positives
  mutate(poslag = lag(pos)) %>%
  #Replace NA (first row) with zero
  replace_na (list(poslag = 0)) %>%
  #Get the number of new cases using pos and poslag
  mutate(news = pos - poslag) %>%
  #Get incidence and prevalence
  mutate(incidence = news/neg,
         prevalence = pos/totalID) %>%
  #Stay only with the time, incidence and prevalence columns
  select(time, incidence, prevalence)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   time incidence prevalence
#  <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1     0            0  
#2     2     0.25         0.2
#3     3     0.333        0.4
#4     4     0.5          0.6
```

The incidence values are not the same as the ones you reported; however, I think they were calculated wrongly, as in time 2 there is 1 new positive and 4 negatives, so the incidence should be 1/4 = 0.25, the same applies for the following times.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan. I edited/clarified the example for clarity (see above). Any suggestions on how to go about it for each time point?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jonathan. Actually, for the incidence, you have to divide the new cases with the number of people free of disease. so in time 1 (5 -0 = 5 people are free of disease), in time 2 (5- 0 = 5 people are free of disease), in time 3 (5-1 = 4 people are free of disease) and in time 4 (4-1 = 3 are free of disease). I modified the code and obtained the correct code. I am not sure it is the most efficient but here it is

```
library(tidyverse)
dsn2 %>%
  #Group by time
  group_by(time) %>%
  #Get the sum of positives and negatives, as well as total ID number
  summarise(pos = sum(MI ==1),
            neg = sum(MI ==0),
            totalID = n_distinct(id)) %>%
  #add lagged entry of positives
  mutate(poslag = lag(pos), 
         neglag = lag(neg)) %>%
  #Replace NA with zero in poslag and 1 in neglag (because of the division)
  mutate(poslag = case_when(is.na(poslag) ~ 0, TRUE ~ as.double(poslag)),
         neglag = case_when(is.na(neglag) ~ 1, TRUE ~ as.double(neglag))) %>%
  #Get the number of new cases using pos and poslag
  mutate(news = pos - poslag) %>%
  #Get incidence and prevalence
  mutate(incidence = news/neglag,
         prevalence = pos/totalID) %>%
  #Stay only with the time, incidence and prevalence columns
  select(time, incidence, prevalence)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    time incidence prevalence
#>   <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1     0            0  
#> 2     2     0.2          0.2
#> 3     3     0.25         0.4
#> 4     4     0.333        0.6
```

Does this make sense? Is there another to do this? Thank you so much

Comment: This doesn't 't return the correct result if there is an incidence of the disease at time 1.  I've posted a solution that does.